An error occured which the SQL Server Integration Services Wizard was not preparted to handle
I wanted to import some Excel data but when I open the SQL Server 2022 Import and Export Data (64bit). I get the below error. I am using SSMS 19.3 and Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM) - 16.0.1000.6 (X64). Does Express support SSIS or need to download Dev Server

An error occurred which the SQL Server Integration Services Wizard was not prepared to handle. (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)


Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.ScaleHelper, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. (DTSWizard)

I browsed through various you tube videos and articles where I get suggestion to install developer edition server to solve the problem. Is there any other ways I can run the SQL Server import and export wizard to import the Excel data
